# Remove another user's session

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

There is possible to get another users session? Suppose, there is user with  admin privilegies and I need that admin have functionality, to access another user's session and remove it. (So that another user will automatically logged out).

Is there some tools in laravel for this? or I need do same things, as I would do for native PHP application ?

Comment: just remove the session stored in the database.

Comment: Why will admin make someone log out?

Comment: make a controller and fetch the active sessions from the DB and remove the one you want

Comment: @ vivek_23 - If admin have privilege to block/remove user, that blocked user should automatically logged out (of course if he/she is currently logged in).

Comment: @OMiShah - but how I can check which session belongs which user ?

Comment: sessions are unique and differenciated by ``user_id``

Answer (score 1):

- Have an admin panel and have the setting to block the user.
- Have a column in your database table, say `is_blocked` with datatype as `tinyint`, with `1` meaning the user is `blocked`.
- In your application, have an additional check of whether the current logged in user is blocked in a custom made middleware. If yes, log them out, else continue with request target.

**Middleware Snippet:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Session;

class IsBlockedMiddleware{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){   
        Auth::user()->refresh();
        if(Auth::user()->blocked === 1){
            Auth::logout();
            Session::flash('error','Your account is blocked'); // show the flash message in your blade file            
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }       

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Blocking a user is not the same as ending their session.

Comment: @meagar But OP gave me this as a reason to do so.

Comment: @meagar - Why not? if you block/remove user, then why you should give them persmission, to continue using application as an active/logged user ?

Comment: @otar If that's your use case then you should clarify your question. There are lots of reasons to end another users session without destroying their account or blocking future logins. Ending a specific session is not the same as disabling an account

Comment: @meagar Just curious, when would we end other users' sessions apart from when we block or remove a user?

Comment: When their account shows indications of compromise, such as being left logged in on a stolen device or a public computer.

Comment: @meager Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Nice solution by @nice_dev, I tried this in Laravel 9 and some changes were made. Here is my middleware.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Application\Admin\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LogoutBlockedUserMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure(Request): (Response|RedirectResponse) $next
     * @return Response|RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response|RedirectResponse
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->isBlocked()) {

            Auth::guard('web')->logout();
            $request->session()->invalidate();
            $request->session()->regenerateToken();

            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Anyone looking for this solution in future may find this helpful. Credits to nice_dev!